# C++ std::localtime daylight saving time rule (dst) european vs american

Tags: c++, c++11, dst, localtime

I've problem with use of the std::localtime function. When I transform a std::time_t to a local struct tm, it always use the american daylight saving time whereas I want to use the european one (France).

UTC : 03/19/16 16:56 is transformed in Local : 03/19/16 18:56.

At this date, normally, local is 17:56 (UTC+1). The DST happens on the 27th in France.
After several tests, it seems that the used DST is based on the american rule : DST happens on second sunday in march.

I've also changed the TZ environement variable, but it also fails.

---

`

```
if( putenv( "TZ=CET-1CEST-2,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3" ) != 0 ) { 
     std::cout << "Unable to set TZ" << std::endl; 
} else { 
   tz = getenv("TZ"); 
   if (tz) std::cout << tz << std::endl; 
   else std::cout << "TZ not defined" << std::endl; tzset(); 
}

struct std::tm t;
t.tm_sec = 0;
t.tm_min = 56;
t.tm_hour = 18;
t.tm_mday = 19;
t.tm_mon = 3-1;
t.tm_year = 2016-1900;
t.tm_isdst = -1;
std::time_t tt = std::mktime(&t);
std::cout << "UTC: " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&tt), "%c %Z") << '\n'; // UTC : 03/19/16 16:56
std::cout << "local: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tt), "%c %Z") << '\n'; // Local : 03/19/16 18:56 (not waited result)
```

`

As a precision, I use the bcc32c compiler (the embarcadero C++ clang based computer).

I hope I'm clear enough and you'll be able to help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is probably an environment thing too, what is your OS?

Comment: Does your environment have `<chrono>`?

Comment: The OS I use is Win 7 32 bits. I used <chrono>

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++11 (or later) available, which includes `<chrono>`, and if you are willing to work with the `<chrono>` system.  And if you are willing to use this [free, open-source timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).  Then this is a very simple matter:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto zt = make_zoned("Europe/Paris", sys_days{2016_y/mar/19} + 18h + 56min);
    std::cout << format("%m/%d/%y %H:%M %Z", zt.get_sys_time()) << '\n';
    std::cout << format("%m/%d/%y %H:%M %Z", zt) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
03/19/16 18:56 UTC
03/19/16 19:56 CET
```

In short, you form one `zoned_time` by pairing a timezone of your choosing
("Europe/Paris"), with a `sys_time` (UTC).  Then you can format that `zoned_time` both by extracting the `sys_time` back out of it, and by formatting the `zoned_time` itself, which will use the `local_time` of the `zoned_time`.

I attempted to use formatting that was consistent with your comments.  You could of course you any format you want.  You can also include any `std::locale` your system supports as the first argument in the calls to  `format` (which `%c` would take advantage of).

You can also extract individual fields both from the `sys_time` and from the `local_time` if you need to, or do other date or time computations.  This is more than just a formatting library.

If you are starting with a `time_t`, there is a static member function of `std::chrono::system_clock` to convert a `time_t` to a `system_clock::time_point`.  You can then use that `time_point` in place of `sys_days{2016_y/mar/19} + 18h + 56min` in this example:

```
auto zt = make_zoned("Europe/Paris", system_clock::from_time_t(t));
```

Comment: @MathiasVantieghem:  If you have any troubles or questions, you can chat on gitter (linked off the README at github).  Start a github issue.  Ping me here.  Or email me directly (just search for my email address, it is easy to find).